# Model View Controller. What is Model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

## What is model ?

I am an ASP.Net WebForms developer.
I have been studying MVC for couple of days.

I can understand the concept of Controller and View but What is Model ?

Is it Data ?
Does it have to be with LINQ or we can use traditional stored procedures ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it Data ?

Generally it's data and behavior.  When you go about designing your model I'd suggest forgetting about "database" altogether.  The [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) book has an excellent example of this.

> Does it have to be with LINQ or we can use traditional stored
>   procedures ?

Try and create your model to be persistent ignorant.  Lots of answer mention a database but ideally the model shouldn't have any knowledge of how it's persisted.  And in some cases some not all parts of the model will be persisted.  Look at the [kigg](http://kigg.codeplex.com/) source.  It shows a clear separation between the model and the persistence.  It shows implementing EF and Linq as two different options.

IMO, The ASP.NET MVC in Action books do a great job of laying out the different parts of MVC and discussing the different "models", ViewModel vs Entity Model, etc.

edit: Maybe the question should be, In (Domain driven design || Data driven design), what is the model?

Comment: So can a dataset be a Model ? Sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: n how can a model be be behavior ? please explain

Comment: Check out http://code.google.com/p/ndddsample/ look at the model.  As an example, the Cargo entity has, SpecifyNewRoute.

Comment: Generally you'd map results, in the form of a DataSet to a collection of an entities.  You asked if you could use traditional SP's, sure.  I believe http://myshop.codeplex.com/ is an example of using ADO.NET for persistence.

Answer (score 2):

In abstract level, `Model` is all about interacting with database and data.

There is no hard and fast rule to get interact with database via LINQ or some other  traditional stored procedures. It entirely depends upon the context.

BTW, when you follow `Skinny Controller and Fat Model` approach, the businesss logic may get into `Model` or you can develop `Service layer` to handle business logic But I prefer to have business logic in Model.

Answer (score 2):

Model means your **domain model** or data. It does not have to be necessarily LINQ objects. You can create **POCO** classes for your domain model and use any data access method to fill data to it. You may use LinqtoSQL or EntityFrameWork **or Plain ADO.NET** for that. It is completely upto you.

When you look for MVC samples, you mostly see sample code/ program with LINQ to SQL or EntityFramework. Those are ORMS to help the developer to avoid writing all that mapping code from DataReader to POCO classes.

Remember MVC does not worry about what the data access method is. MCV is a development pattern which separates these different concerns into different layers.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, It is related to data.

> MODEL is an object representing data or even activity, e.g. a database
>   table or even some plant-floor production-machine process.

2) and technically, you can get it through Linq OR  Stored procedure.

Comment: Indeed Models make me lost. Does it table?! some times you feel that it is just a field of the table or a row!

Answer (score 1):

A model is the single, definitive source of data about your data. It contains the essential fields and behaviors of the data you’re storing. Generally, each model maps to a single database table.

Comment: Didn't get the point "each model maps to a single database table."? Can you make it more clear?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It depends. It sometimes might be persisted in a table. Sometimes in a NoSQL database. Sometimes in a file. Maybe XML. Or Amazon S3 or Simple DB. Or it's from some external web service. Or be an aggregate of several sources. Or it's not persisted at all.

Comment: Which is why I said generally